# unhandled rejections holding references

Tags: node.js

I have a doubt while running below JavaScript in node.js.

```
var z = new Image();
function x()
{
    var promise = new Promise();
    return promise;
}
var promise = x();
promise.then(function(){});
..........
promise.reject(z);
```

There is no reject handler added to promise returned by x(). But, at some point if we are sending reject with response value z, whether z will be garbage collected or will be still held due to unhandled rejection having reference to it. But, when I add catch/reject handler to promise, I am seeing garbage collection happens for z.

Please clarify why garbage collection not happening for Z, when passed to unhandled rejection.

Comment: `z` looks like it is global to the file since it is instantiated at the top level of the module. This means that it would not be garbage collected since a global place still holds a reference. Read more about garbage collection [here](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-performance-garbage-collection/)

Answer (score -1):

That's not how you use [native A+] promises.

Try like this:

```
function x()
{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        if(success()) {
            resolve(success_val);
        } else {
            reject(new Error("fail!"));
        }
    });
}

let promise = x();
promise.then(function(){});
```

You can't reject a promise outside of where it's created. You have to use the (resolve,reject) constructor callback.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, the question is about garbage collected and why `z` is not garbage collection when a `rejection` occurs and is handled by `process.on('unhandledRejection, (err) => { });` because a `catch()` is absent from the promise chain.

Comment: @peteb Well I can't answer the question without a working example. Typically, if something is holding a reference to a value, it will not be garbage collected.

Comment: Then don't answer it? Also you can use `Promise.reject()` anywhere in a promise chain to cause a rejection, not just where the Promise is created.

Comment: @peteb I'm not sure what version of Node you're using but `new Promise()` gives an error: "TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function". `Promise.reject()` with a capital `P` *does* work, but that's not what OP wrote.